# Limit of vector sequence

Tags: matrices, limits, vectors

Given a diagonalizable matrix $A$ and arbitary vector $v_0$. There is a sequence of vectors: $v_{i+1}= \alpha_i\cdot Av_i$ ($\alpha_i$ is а scalar such that first coordinate of $v_{i+1}$ is equal to 1).

Prove, that such sequence of vectors has limit (coordinate-wise convergence).

I tried to transform reccurent formula to $v_{i+1} = \alpha_0 \dots \alpha_i A^i v_0$ and do something with it, but properties of $\alpha_i$ sequence are unclear.

Comment: Although the statement of your question has a problem right now, I think it can be fixed. This is related to power iterations to find the highest eigenvalue. Under suitable contiions, your sequence $v_i$ will converge to the eigenvector with highest eigenvalue. More info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration

Comment: @G.Fougeron, could you tell what these suitable conditions are?

Comment: It's unclear to me. If I were you, I'd work them out from the article I linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter exemple : $$ A = \begin{pmatrix}0&1 \\ 1 &0 \end{pmatrix}$$ $$v = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
$\alpha_0 = ?$